# Data types and how rapidminer emphasizes them

Tags: data-science, rapidminer

Fairly new to rapidminer and data science.

I imported data (it's very wide, so it took a while to classify all of the data types). I put the data through random forest and it appears to have emphasized the wrong things. I believe this is due to incorrect data type classification. I can't seem to find good data type documentation and am looking for an explanation of how rapidminer looks at each.

For example, I have some columns with 90% blanks and a couple filled it. I labeled this as "nominal" and rapid miner weighted this column heavily. I wanted it to weigh the dates columns more since I'm trying to predict cycle tmie.... any help or insight very much appreciated!

Some of the data types available are:
Nominal 
Polynomial
binomial
dates
text
etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if I got your question correctly, but neither RapidMiner or the RandomForest algorithm emphasized a certain data type over another.
So if the algorithm puts more importance on the nominal columns, it is because the strongly separate your example.

The different data types in RapidMiner are the to allow, dis-allow certain operations. 
Classic example are phone numbers. If they are stored as a real number, you could get something like a square root or averages, which does not make sense. So storing them as String (or Nominal) makes more sense.

If you want to exclude certain attributes, you could try a feature selection or dimensionality reduction method (like PCA or the *Remove Correlated*, *Remove Useless* operators.

Also feel free to ask further, or re-post, questions in the RapidMiner [community forum](https://community.rapidminer.com/).